# Creating a Person class with Name and Address subclasses?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

For an assignment I am designing a simple "chatroom" system. It is very rudimentary and simply involves objects of a Person class sending messages to each other through a separate Chatroom object.
Below is my Person class (did not include getter/setter methods for sake of brevity).

```
public class Person {

protected String firstName;
protected String lastName;
protected String message;

Person(String fn, String ln)
{
    firstName = fn;
    lastName = ln;
}
public void sendMessage(String msg, Person rec)
{
    rec.receiveMessage(msg);
}

public String receiveMessage(String msg)
{
    message = msg;
}

}
```

these Person objects are instantiated and send messages to each other through the Chatroom class using the sendMessage method.

Now I am supposed to design a larger Person class, into multiple classes by adding Address, Name and Contact classes to the multi class system. The problem is I don't know how to associate these classes with the Person class. At first I tried to make an inheritance relationship with the Name class adding the middleInitial field, but i dont see the utility in this.

```
public class Name extends Person {

    protected String middleInitial;

    Name(String fn, String ln) {
    super(fn, ln);
}

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

    }

    public String getMI()
    {
        return middleInitial;
    }

    public void setMI(String mi)
    {
        middleInitial = mi;
    }
```

I don't understand the need for these separate classes, couldn't all this information be stored in the Person object? Can someone help me understand a way to design these classes separately but all be part of the Person object?

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Just as an example - Right now your person just has 3 `String`s. You can cram an address in a String but it is not nice to work with. Instead, you create a class called `Address` that will contain inside of it things like a `String` for the street name, maybe an `int` for the house number, etc... Then instead of your Person class having `String myAddress = "123 MyStreet"` you would have `Address myAddress = new Address(123, "MyStreet")` Then the address is easier to work with. `Name`/`Address` should not extend `Person` in any way - they are separate. It's called composition.

Comment: Since when does a Person _is a_ Name make any sense whatsoever? I don't know about you, but I _have a_ name. This is one of the clearest cases for prefer composition over inheritance I have ever seen...

Answer (score 0):

In this case - yes name should be part of Person. In OOP (Object Oriented Programming) "extends" means "is-a". In your case "Name" is definitely not "is-a" Person. Person should contain name - so "Name" should be a property and not "extend" person.